# Firebase Realtime Database update every second with Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cron

I am trying to create an auction portal with Firebase Realtime Database and Node.js. I am storing auction start,end time and remaining time value is getting updated by Node setInterval() function. Clients observe the remaining time and update as the DB is updated.

Every thing works fine except the CPU usage is off the roof. What could be a better solution to this ?

Following is my code :

```
var query = usersRef.orderByKey();

query.on('value', function (snap) {

  setInterval(function () {

    snap.forEach(function (item) {

      var current_item = item.val();

      var startDate = current_item.sdate;
      var endDate = current_item.edate;

      var start_ts = moment(moment(), "YYYY/MM/DD H:mm:ss");
      var end_ts = moment(endDate, "YYYY/MM/DD H:mm:ss");

      var duration = moment.duration(end_ts.diff(start_ts));

      var remainT = moment.utc(duration.as('milliseconds')).format("DD:HH:mm:ss")

      var hopperRef = usersRef.child(item.key);
      hopperRef.update({
        "rtime": remainT
      });

    });

    console.log("Updated");    

  }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: While you can store the remaining time, it is also a pure function of the start and end time. Why don't you let the clients order by end time, and calculate the time remaining themselves?

Comment: Yes it is a function, but remaining time is calculated end time - current. As the current time is based on clients machine, which is may not be sync correctly, will create issue.